# Scanned image heatmap in java

Tags: java, image-processing

My issue is this:
I have a black and white scanned image and I need to convert it into a heatmap.If I scan my hand for example, where the pressure is higher the scanned skin will be whiter, where it is less pressure the skin is darker so I need the white to be pure red and the black to be blue while the greys between to vary from yellow to green. So highest pressure red->orange->yellow->green->blue.

Where can I get a java api/sdk/program to do that for me.

Thanks

Comment: You might need to code that feature your self based on some image processing package. (In python I would use PIL. Here is a thread on PIL equivalent java: http://www.mail-archive.com/clojure@googlegroups.com/msg10553.html) which recommends http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your black/white image can be interpreted as a double X from 0 (meaning black) to 1 (meaning white).

**Now take the [HSV](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) color space:**

It consists of a triple *(H,S,V)* of doulbes (from (0,0,0) to (1,1,1), where H (roughly) resembles the color and S and V modify the color. If you look at the color which different values of H resemble, you will see, that they exactly it your needs. So simple construct a new HSV-Color (X,0.5,0.5) (where X is your gray scale value, change the 0.5 to your needs). If you need RGB-Colors, take the well known [formula](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Converting_to_RGB) to convert.

Comment: thanks man but tell me of a jar or jdk to download in order to solve this.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know one, i think you must write these 5 lines of code by your self.